# Sharing templates across components in Vue

Tags: templates, inheritance, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm using Vue with Vuetify and I have a few components that are pretty similar, yet different enough to justify making them separate components.

To avoid duplicating code, I created a base component that they extend to share the script they have in common. But in this scenario their templates are all **exactly the same**. Something like this:

```
<v-card class="mb-3">
    <v-card-text>
        <v-form>
            <v-textarea
                v-model="question.text"
                label="Question"
                :auto-grow=true
                rows="1"
                required
                v-if="!options.richText"
            >
                <template slot="append">
                    <v-icon
                            @click="toggleVariable('richText')"
                            v-if="!options.richText"
                            title="Advanced text editor"
                    >format_color_text</v-icon>
                </template>
            </v-textarea>
            <tinymce v-model="question.text" v-if="options.richText"></tinymce>
            <answer
                v-for="(answer, answerIndex) in question.answers"
                :key="answer.id"
                v-on:remove-answer="removeAnswer(answerIndex)"
                :options="options"
                :config="question.config"
                :answer-index="answerIndex"
                :answer="answer"
                :numAnswers="question.answers.length"
            ></answer>
        </v-form>
    </v-card-text>
    <question-options
        :options="options"
        :config="question.config"
        :questionIndex="questionIndex"
        v-on:add-answer="addAnswer"
        v-on:toggle-variable="toggleVariable"
    ></question-options>
</v-card>
```

What would be a good way to allow all three components to share the same template?

I toyed with the idea of **scoped slots**, but then, if I understand correctly, this whole template would have to go in the parent component along with references to all the variables and functions. And then I'd have to repeat this in all parent components that want to use these child components.

What could I do to avoid having to repeat all this code in all my similar components?

Comment: Which parts will be different in the various components? And what do you need to pass from the parent?

Comment: Each component has a few methods and settings that are different. The differences are in the `<script></script>` section of each component. All I'm passing them from the parent is the `question` and `questionIndex` props.